# Output specific value from Json object retrieved from external function

Tags: python, json, exiftool

I'm having trouble getting the proper output value when doing

```
print metadata["File:FileSize"]
```

It gives me `list indices must be a integer, not str` error.
I thought `json.loads` returns a dictionary.

The variable `metadata` is retrieved like this from exiftool in a class as such:

```
def get_metadata(self, *filenames):
    return json.loads(self.execute("-G", "-j", "-n", *filenames))
```

and in the main program flow I do this:

```
metadata = exif.get_metadata(fileName)
print metadata
print metadata["File:FileSize"]
```

Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample of a raw exiftool query:

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "/media/mango/MF-HDD-277/01_audio/Computer Arts royalty-free audio samples/Disc 191 - soundsnap/ComputerArtsDisc191_SoundSnapSamples_088_Bend03.wav",
  "ExifTool:ExifToolVersion": 9.13,
  "File:FileName": "ComputerArtsDisc191_SoundSnapSamples_088_Bend03.wav",
  "File:Directory": "/media/mango/MF-HDD-277/01_audio/Computer Arts royalty-free audio samples/Disc 191 - soundsnap",
  "File:FileSize": 146948,
  "File:FileModifyDate": "2010:10:24 11:17:20-04:00",
  "File:FileAccessDate": "2014:01:29 15:58:48-05:00",
  "File:FileInodeChangeDate": "2014:01:21 13:28:00-05:00",
  "File:FilePermissions": 711,
  "File:FileType": "WAV",
  "File:MIMEType": "audio/x-wav",
  "RIFF:Encoding": 1,
  "RIFF:NumChannels": 2,
  "RIFF:SampleRate": 44100,
  "RIFF:AvgBytesPerSec": 176400,
  "RIFF:BitsPerSample": 16,
  "Composite:Duration": 0.833038548752834
}]
```

Comment: Try to print the raw string without calling `json.loads` on it and check if it's a javascript object or not. Also, what's the output of printing metadata?

Comment: I added the output of a raw query (no json.loads)

Comment: This table shows what json.loads returns for what input http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw query is returning a javascript object inside an array. When you parse the JSON with `json.loads`, you get the dict inside a list. So, to access the attributes, do `metadata[0]["File:FileSize"]`.

Or change the `get_metadata` method to directly return the dict.

```
def get_metadata(self, *filenames):
    return json.loads(self.execute("-G", "-j", "-n", *filenames))[0]
```

And no, `json.loads` not only returns dictionaries. The [table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table) Tim linked in his comment specifies the JSON to Python translations.

Comment: ah, I see, your second suggesting is the best one I see! thanks!